# How to get the object from a Django Rest Framework serializer init method?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have my **serializers** code set up as follows:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
     * Serializes Products.
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print kwargs.pop('product_passed')
        super(ProductSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Now, this serializer is being called from a view using the code below:

```
product_passed = Product.objects.get(pk=pk)
product_serializer = ProductSerializer(product_passed)
```

What I want to do is call the product_passed from my serializer init method. How can I do this? Right now, my method does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass it like this:

```
product_serializer = ProductSerializer(product_passed, product_passed= product_passed)
```

And access it from kwargs: `kwargs.get('product_passed')`

Comment: if use `pop` for exclude errors best solution is use default value